# Positive and negative subsetting using dplyr::contains() and dplyr::select() in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to achieve positive subsetting specifically using a combination of `dplyr::select()` and dplyr::contains()`, with the goal being to subset by multiple string matches.

Minimal working example: when starting off with `df1` and doing negative subsetting, I generate `df2` as expected. In contrast, when attempting positive subsetting of `df1`, I generate `df3` (no columns) when I'd have expected something like `df4`. Thanks for any help.

```
df1 <- data.frame("ppt_paint"=c(45,98,23),"het_heating"=c(1,1,2) ,"orm_wood"=c("QQ","OA","BB"), "hours"=c(4,6,4), "distance"=c(23,65,21))
df2 <- df1 %>% select(-contains("ppt_")) %>% select(-contains("het_")) %>% select(-contains("orm_"))
df3 <- df1 %>% select(contains("ppt_")) %>% select(contains("het_")) %>% select(contains("orm_")) 
df4 <- data.frame("ppt_paint"=c(45,98,23),"het_heating"=c(1,1,2) ,"orm_wood"=c("QQ","OA","BB"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think (and have a look to the resulting `data.frame`) to what happens after: `df1 %>% select(contains("ppt_"))`. As asked, it only retains the *only* column that contains `"ppt_"`. Further expressions cannot work as you expect since other columns, no matter what you're feeding `select` with, are "no longer" there.

You can keep the same idea but *combine*  in the same `select` you three keys:

```
df1 %>% select(matches("ppt_"), matches("het_"), matches("orm_"))
  ppt_paint het_heating orm_wood
1        45           1       QQ
2        98           1       OA
3        23           2       BB
```

Alternatively, you can do it with `matches`, that accepts regular expressions:

```
df1 %>% select(matches(c("ppt_|het_|orm_")))
  ppt_paint het_heating orm_wood
1        45           1       QQ
2        98           1       OA
3        23           2       BB
```

And by the way you can also use it to shorten your "negative" indexing:

```
df1 %>% select(-matches("ppt_|het_|orm_"))
  hours distance
1     4       23
2     6       65
3     4       21
```